# Why i can't use comand "git commit --amend" and push that to github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-amend

firstly I cloned my own repo from github, because i wanna amend the last commit, so i type "git commit --amend" and push to github, but some errors occur. Some guys said that the operation doesn't allowed by github, unless make another commit, Is that true?  and how can i amend the last commit on github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You totally can do this. However `--amend` rewrites history so you have to force the push to github. After using `--amend` just use

```
git push origin {branch_name} --force
```

**Use with caution. This will overwrite history on the remote.**